# How to prove existence of the language

Tags: complexity-theory, np, decision-problem, nondeterminism

Consider such question:

(*Prove or disprove*) There exists a language in $TIME(2^{n^2})$ that is not in $NTIME(n)$.

I guess that answer is yes because $TIME(2^{n^2})$ and $NTIME(n)$ are totally different classes ($TIME(2^{n})$ and $NTIME(n)$ are the same classes, i guess). How to prove it strictly? (Or my guess is incorrect?)

Comment: Use $NTIME(n) \subseteq TIME(2^{O(n)})$ together with the deterministic time hierarchy theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the following two facts:

- $\mathsf{NTIME}(n) \subseteq \mathsf{TIME}(2^{O(n)})$, by deterministic simulation of nondeterminism.
- $\mathsf{TIME}(2^{O(n)}) \subsetneq \mathsf{TIME}(2^{n^2})$, by the time hierarchy theorem.